# Is it possible to keep folds saved when I copy from one file to another?

Tags: command-line, cut-copy-paste, folding

I've recently discovered I can fold blocks of code with Vim by using `zf`.Then I can open and close them with `zo` and `zc`... I've also seen [this solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37558470/14739472) that has a `vimrc` configuration that allows me to automatically save my folds when I close and when I open my files. However, if I copy my folded files with a `cp` command like:

```bash
cp myFoldedFile.js myNewFile.js
```

I end up losing all my folds in `myNewFile.js`. I've also tried saving it from inside Vim with `:w! /home/user/myNewFile.js` but it didn't work as well. In my case, it'd work well if there was a Vim command that I could use from inside it instead of using the command line as my original sample. Is it possible? Is there any way of copying my files and keeping their folds?

Comment: If you are ok with having fold-markers inside the file, you can use `foldmethod=marker`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Perfect, just using `set foldmethod=marker` in my `vimrc` file was enough for what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `:set[local] foldmethod=marker` is the most portable in that it actually denotes folds in the file using special (and customizable) markers. Even programs other than vim can be told (or taught) to recognize these markers. Because the content of the file contains the fold information, copying the file copies the folds.